# How to escape from command line interface in fedora21?

Tags: fedora, terminal, gnome, shutdown

I was stuck in command line interface of Linux Fedora 21. I don't know how to get to the GNOME. I forced my laptop to shutdown by hitting the power button several times. Now I really want to know how to get to GNOME from CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your laptop *normally* boot to GNOME, and when it came back up after being forced off, did it come back to GNOME? Assuming so, you either got there by a crash, or by inadvertantly switching virtual terminals (VTs). You can do this intentionally by pressing `CTRL-ALT-F1`, `CTRL-ALT-F2`, `CTRL-ALT-F3`, and so on. (Actually, when in text mode, you can leave off the ctrl, and just do `ALT-F#`, but it doesn't hurt to add `CTRL` in any case if it's easier to just remember one thing.)

By Fedora (and upstream systemd, I think) convention, there should be a text console on vt6 — `CTRL-ALT-F6`, and it's *most likely* that the GUI is running on vt1 — `CTRL-ALT-F1`. So pressing `ALT-F1` (or `CTRL-ALT-F1`) *should* get you back. (If you have multiple users logged in at once, various other vts may be in use.)

If that doesn't work, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you may be looking to change from the character based console to the gnome/GUI one. This is controlled by the system boot target. You need to have the host boot up with the graphical.target (the GUI). 
e.g.
To get to that run level, log in as root and type

```
systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

on the command line.

To make that persist over reboots you need to move the default.target link to point to the graphical target link. first, just to check which target you are defaulting too

```
ls -ltr /lib/systemd/system/default.target
```

just to check which target you are defaulting too

```
rm /lib/systemd/system/default.target
ln -s  /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target /lib/systemd/system/default.target
```

now next time you reboot. it will come up in graphical mode.